# What comes after $1$, $\omega$, $\epsilon_0$, ...?

Tags: terminology, education, computability, ordinals

Note that I am *not* a mathematician. I'm working from sources like *Gödel, Escher, Bach* and *[Transfinite Ordinals and Their Notations For The Uninitiated](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~levitz/ords.ps)*. Therefore, I'm looking for the most basic, non-specialist, pop-science answer you can give me. (Your answer will undoubtedly include "It depends," but I hope it will not consist *solely* of those two words.)

One of the intriguing claims in *Gödel, Escher, Bach* is "there is no recursive rule for naming ordinals" — that is, as you count higher, you'll end up needing new names not just on a regular basis but on an *irregular* basis, such that you can't even make up a rule for naming the new numbers anymore. I understand how the ordinal numbers begin:

$$
   1, 2, 3, \dots, \omega \\
   \omega + 1, \omega + 2, \dots, 2\omega \\
$$
(Please excuse my writing $2\omega$ instead of $\omega2$. This should set your expectations correctly for the kind of answer I'd like!) Then we just keep finding sequences and taking suprema:
$$
   2\omega, 3\omega, 4\omega, \dots, \omega^2 \\
   \omega^2, \omega^3, \omega^4, \dots, \omega^\omega \\
   \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega+1}, \dots, \omega^{2\omega}, \dots, \omega^{\omega^{\omega}} \\
   \omega, \omega^{\omega}, \omega^{\omega^{\omega}}, \dots, \epsilon_0
$$
At this point ($\epsilon_0$) we encounter the need to introduce a new name for a supremum, for only the second time ever. (The first time was when we introduced $\omega$.) At this point my book-learning runs out, but I intuit that we continue:
$$
    \epsilon_0 + 1, \epsilon_0 + 2, \dots, \epsilon_0 + \omega \\
    \epsilon_0 + 2\omega, \epsilon_0 + \omega^2, \epsilon_0 + \omega^\omega, \dots, 2\epsilon_0 \\
    2\epsilon_0, 3\epsilon_0, \dots, \omega\epsilon_0 \\
    \omega\epsilon_0, \omega^2\epsilon_0, \omega^\omega\epsilon_0, \omega^{\omega^\omega}\epsilon_0, \dots, \epsilon_0^2 \\
    \epsilon_0^2, \epsilon_0^3, \dots, \epsilon_0^\omega \\
    \epsilon_0^\omega, \epsilon_0^{2\omega}, \epsilon_0^{\omega^2}, \epsilon_0^{\omega^\omega}, \dots, \epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0} \\
    \epsilon_0, \epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0}, \epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0}}, \dots, ??
$$

And now I need a name for the supremum of *this* sequence. Intuitively I'd like to call it something like $\epsilon_1$; but I bet it has a "real" name. (I also wouldn't be at all surprised if there were some ordinal equivalent of the Continuum Hypothesis, such that *technically* $\epsilon_1$ might or might not be the name of this number, but where for pop-science purposes we can treat it as such, as long as we preface our remarks with an incantation like "Assuming ZFC...")

Intuitively then I'd eventually need the name $\epsilon_2$ for the supremum of

$$
    \epsilon_1, \epsilon_1^{\epsilon_1}, \epsilon_1^{\epsilon_1^{\epsilon_1}}, \dots
$$

and then $\epsilon_3, \epsilon_4, \dots$ before finally needing the name $\epsilon_\omega$ for the supremum of *that* sequence...

Now, everything from $\epsilon_1$ onward was just my blind conjecture; but *assuming* I'm roughly on the right track, I do see shades of the Tortoise and Achilles here. But — so far, I haven't had any trouble making up names for all these ordinal numbers. The real trouble starts when I get to

$$
    \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3, \dots, \epsilon_\omega \\
    \epsilon_\omega, \epsilon_{\omega^\omega}, \dots, \epsilon_{\epsilon_0} \\
    \epsilon_{\epsilon_0}, \epsilon_{\epsilon_1}, \epsilon_{\epsilon_2}, \dots, \epsilon_{\epsilon_\omega} \\
    \epsilon_{\epsilon_\omega}, \epsilon_{\epsilon_{\omega^\omega}}, \epsilon_{\epsilon_{\omega^{\omega^\omega}}}, \dots, \epsilon_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}} \\
    \epsilon_0, \epsilon_{\epsilon_0}, \epsilon_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}}, \dots, ??
$$

Uh-oh! Now I *really* need a new name! I could call this number $\zeta_0$ (again, I bet it has a real name, if I'm not off in the weeds yet), and then keep going: $\zeta_0, \zeta_0 + 1, \zeta_0 + \omega, \zeta_0 + \epsilon_0, 2\zeta_0, \dots$

What I still don't intuitively "get" is why *GEB* says "there is no recursive rule for naming ordinals". I mean, my method of making up names seems to be working so far! But I admit I've only gone 3 steps ($\omega, \epsilon, \zeta$) and there's an infinite number of steps left to go. And then there'll be an $\omega$'th step after *that*, right?

But still, I don't intuitively "get" where this recursion breaks down, if it does.

So this is kind of a two-parter: Number one, if I've made any major errors of fact in the above, please correct me (especially about "official" names for $\epsilon_1$ and $\zeta_0$). Number two, please explain *GEB*'s claim that "there is no recursive rule for naming ordinals."

In case it helps, I *am* fairly familiar with Cantor's diagonal argument and the proof of the undecidability of the Halting Problem.

Comment: $\epsilon_1$ is indeed the name of that ordinal.

Comment: Likewise, $\zeta_0$ is the limit of $\epsilon_x$.

Comment: I don't really see why you have contempt for correctness with respect to the order of multiplication ($\omega 2$ vs. $2 \omega$). There is value in respecting conventions / trying to do things properly, even if you're "not a mathematician".

Comment: It's related to the question: [How many angels can dance on the head of a pin?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Kronecker).

Comment: Any naming system is fooled by the question, "What's the set of all ordinals I can name with this naming system? …And what's the first ordinal larger than all of those?" (Note that any naming system will only be able to name countable many things.)

Comment: Since you have the computability tag, it may interest you that $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$ is the first uncomputable ordinal (the Church-Kleene ordinal) and there are other very large uncomputable but also countable ordinals.  You have the admissible ordinals, then the recursively inaccessible, then the hyper recursively inaccessible...

Answer (score 4):

I think you're essentially going after the [Veblen function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function). If I understand it correctly, $\varphi_1(\alpha)$ and $\varphi_2(\alpha)$ are your $\epsilon_\alpha$ and $\zeta_\alpha$. Whatever third symbol you come up with will be $\varphi_3$; whatever $\omega$-eth symbol you come up with will be $\varphi_\omega$.

Eventually you'll have a $\zeta_0$-eth symbol. The Veblen function would write that as $\varphi_{\varphi_2(0)}$. And so on.

But what do we call the limit of $\varphi_0(0)$, $\varphi_{\varphi_0(0)}(0)$, $\varphi_{\varphi_{\varphi_0(0)}(0)}(0)$, etc.? This is the ordinal you get with a subscript going infinitely deep. It would be the first ordinal that can't be written with just the $\varphi$ function. Your scheme will never get you past that barrier. This limit is called the [Feferman–Schütte ordinal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feferman%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtte_ordinal), written $\Gamma_0$.

Comment: My very Achillean response is: Then can't I make $\Gamma_0, \Gamma_1, \Gamma_\omega, \Gamma_{\phi_1(0)}, \Gamma_{\phi_{\phi_1(0)}(0)}, \dots, \Gamma_{\Gamma_0}, \Gamma_{\Gamma_{\Gamma_0}}, \dots, \Delta_0, \dots$? But I guess ultimately we run into trouble when we've exhausted the entire system of "subscripts of any kind of thing whatever" and need to jump outside *that* system, eh?

Comment: @Quuxplusone Yeah, you can always build a _better_ system. What you can't do is build a _complete_ system, one that can name _everything_.

Comment: I suppose that's a fair answer. I wish there were an intuitive-to-me proof of that statement, though, in the way that we can intuitively prove the uncountability of the reals or the undecidability of the Halting Problem. I think your argument above that "any naming system will only be able to name countably many things" might be half of an intuitive proof... except that I intuitively consider "decimal notation" to be a naming system for the reals, of which there are uncountably many... so that argument *seems* to have a hole in it already!

Comment: $\Gamma_0$ isn't the largest named ordinal. There are many other even larger countable ordinals that have been named. But we can always define even better systems. (At some point it gets pointless and most of us stop. But I'm sure there's someone out there who just likes defining ever and ever larger countable ordinals, using ever and ever more complicated systems, just for fun.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone Decimals don't count because you need infinitely many symbols for each "name". I've been assuming we want finitely many symbols for each ordinal name.

Comment: *If* we want finitely many symbols per name, and there are uncountably many ordinals, then that's the final step in an intuitive proof! But the first steps are still missing IMHO: we just have to prove the lemma that we *don't* want to use *infinitely* many symbols per name (this one's probably hard), and the lemma that the ordinals are uncountable (which is probably easy because if they were countable they'd be a set, and I hear they're not a set because something about Russell's paradox?).

Comment: Note that every ordinal we've mentioned so far is countable… and we _can_ form the set of all countable ordinals. This set is uncountable. (It's kind of like how the set of all finite numbers is infinite.) The first uncountable ordinal is labeled $\omega_1$. However, the set of _all_ ordinals doesn't exist (because, if it did, we could take its supremum and get a new ordinal).

Comment: @Quuxplusone For the hint of a proof that there is no way to have a notation that describes all ordinals, you can try the end of my answer.  It quickly shows that no matter what notation you use, there is a limit to how far it can construct, and to reach this limit, you will always need a notation not within any of your previous notations.

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks correct so far.  Likewise, all the naming is done correctly.  However, there are more succinct ways to write all this.  Simply use a two argument [Veblen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function):

$$\varphi_0(x)=\omega^x$$

$$\varphi_\alpha(0)=\sup\{\varphi_\beta^n(0):n<\omega,\beta<\alpha\}$$

$$\varphi_\alpha(x)=\sup\{\varphi_\beta^n(\varphi_\alpha(y)+1):n<\omega,y<x,\beta<\alpha\}$$

where $f^n$ is function iteration.  For $n\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, we have

$$f^n(x)\in\{f(x),f(f(x)),f(f(f(x))),\dots\}$$

This gives

$$\varepsilon_x=\varphi_1(x)$$

$$\zeta_x=\varphi_2(x)$$

$$\eta_x=\varphi_3(x)$$

$$\vdots$$

Now, I believe what GEB means by "there is no recursive rule for naming ordinals" can be explained through an example:

Let $\Gamma_0$ be the [Feferman–Schütte ordinal](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Feferman%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtte_ordinal).  It can be given by

$$f(x)=\varphi_x(0)$$

$$\Gamma_0=\sup\{f^n(1),n<\omega\}$$

The problem here is that it will require ***a different kind of recursion*** to reach this ordinal.  To make it clear, consider the following function:

$$C(0)=\{0,1\}$$

$$C(n+1)=C(n)\cup\{\underbrace{\gamma+\delta,\gamma\delta,\varphi_\gamma(\delta)}:\gamma,\delta\in C(n)\}$$

Basically, starting at $0$ and $1$, then repeatedly apply your recursion.  Your recursion methods are described by the operations presented above the braces.

The problem with this is that you will never reach $\sup\{\gamma:\gamma\in C(\alpha)_n,n<\omega\}$, because to do so would require you to apply an operation ***outside*** of the operations you are given.

Of course, put whatever you want above the braces and you will find that since the surpremum of every set exists, there is no single recursive rule for naming all ordinals (mainly the supremum of all the $C$'s.